# Computed Column -- Comma separated after checking NULL

Tags: sql

am trying to make a Computed Column in SQL.Am having the following scenario.

Say I have column A,B,C  and am creating new Column D which should contain values in Column A,B,C as comma separated

Example(Expected output)

```
A  B  C     D  
1  1  1   1,1,1
2      2   2,2
```

I tried the below code

```
Coalesce(A,'')+','+Coalesce(B,'')+','+Coalesce(C,'')
```

But am getting extra comma added as am appending w/o checking NULL

E

```
xample(my output)

A  B  C     D  
1  1  1   1,1,1
2     2   2,,2
```

What am I missing? What is the best way to implement this?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? In Postgres you can use `concat_ws(',',a,b,c)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An operation including a NULL will return NULL so try this:

```
Coalesce(A+',','')+Coalesce(B+',','')+Coalesce(C,'')
```